# Cannot implicitly convert 'string' to 'System.TypeCode'

Tags: c#, syntax-error

Just wondering if anyone knows how to fix this error? I've also used `TypeCode.` but still no luck. Thanks

```
case typeof(Nullable<int>).ToString(): //<----- error is here
if ((!object.ReferenceEquals(value, DBNull.Value)))
{
    return value;
}
else
{
    return null;
}
```

This is the switch

```
    public static object HandleDBNull(object value, System.Type _type)
{
    switch (Type.GetTypeCode(_type))
    {
```

Thanks again for any help

Comment: Paste the full switch statement, what's there in switch ?

Comment: What's in the `switch`? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: `Type.GetTypeCode` expects return as `System.Type`, where the case expects `System.Nullable`1[System.Int32]` string - there's `InvalidCastException` happens.

Comment: well... `typeof(Nullable<int>).ToString()` *isn't* a typecode; what do you expect the result to be, and why? what are you trying to do here? I *suspect* that `Nullable.GetUnderlyingType` might be your friend here

Comment: your code won't compile because needs a constant value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ultimately, `typeof(Nullable<int>)` isn't a `TypeCode`, and the string representation of that isn't a `TypeCode`. There is no `TypeCode` that represents `Nullable<int>` *specifically*.

You can use `Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(type)` to check that something is `Nullable<T>` and get the `T` at the same time (it returns `null` if not), and you can use `Type.GetTypeCode` on the result of that, but: I suspect that in your case, using `TypeCode` *at all* may be an error, and simply checking the type itself (`if (type == typeof(int?)) {...}`) may be better.

Comment: How do i pass an int into the `case Nullable.GetUnderlyingType()` expression?? Sorry I'm new to this

Comment: @K--- you don't, exactly; to check if something is `int?`, the easiest check is: `type == typeof(int?)`. The `var t = Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(type)` approach is intended for when you want to handle multiple different `T` of `Nullable<T>`. If you only care about `Nullable<int>`, just check `type == typeof(int?)`

Comment: @K--- additional note: you seem to be using a `value` which I assume is an `object`. There is **no such thing** as an `object` that contains a `Nullable<T>` value - during the boxing process, it either becomes a `null` reference, or a boxed `T` - meaning: an `int?` value will become either `null` or a boxed `int`. So if you're using `value.GetType()`, it will **never, not once ever** return `typeof(int?)`

Answer (score 1):

The type you use in the `switch` statement has to match the type in the `case` statements, where currently you're comparing a `TypeCode` to a `string`.

The [`TypeCode`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.typecode(v=vs.110).aspx) enumeration only contains values for the primitive types, and all others will be `TypeCode.Object`. So you can't get a *specific* `TypeCode` for the `Nullable<int>` type.