# VB.NET to C# conversion error

Tags: c#, syntax-error

I am trying to convert the following VB code into C#

VB Code:

```
Public Class function_library
  Public Shared Function handle_dbnull(ByVal value As Object, ByVal _type As System.Type) As Object
     Select Case _type.ToString
          Case GetType(Date).ToString, GetType(DateTime).ToString
             If Not IsDBNull(value) Then
                 Return value
             Else
                 Return New DateTime(0)
             End If
     End Select

     Return value
  End Function
End Class
```

The current C# implementation I have is:

```
public static object HandleDBNull(object value, Type _type)
{
    switch (Type.GetTypeCode(_type))
    {
         case typeof(DateTime?).ToString(): // This produces a cannot convert string to System.TypeCode error
            if ((!ReferenceEquals(value, DBNull.Value)))
            {
                return value;
            }
            else
            {
                return null;
            }
    }
}
```

I have tried using the web links provided within other Stackoverflow questions, as well as an online VB to C# converter, but both don't seem to have helped solve my issue.

Any advice on what I might be doing wrong or how to go about solving this issue would be great,

Luke

Comment: What is the error? That's essential for the question. Don't hide it in a code comment

Comment: typeof(DateTime?).ToString():  why is there a ? mark after DateTime

Comment: [Hmmm...](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44671596/579895)

Comment: @Frost_Mourne the ? means nullable

Comment: In your VB code you compare strings, in the C# version you compare a `TypeCode` with a string. Why you use `GetTypeCode` at all?

Comment: oh thanks i learned something then luke:)

Comment: @TimSchmelter I used `GetTypeCode` because I am casing on multiple dtypes such as ints, string, char, and bool. apologies

Answer (score 1):

try like this

```
  case TypeCode.DateTime:
```

If not check this link out see if it helps u [TypeCode Enumeration](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.typecode(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You have switch(TypeCode) and in "case" you have string.
Change switch to string:

```
switch (_type.ToString())
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that it's easier to implement C# code *from scratch*.

If I understand you right, you want:

1. return `value` if `value` is not `DBNull.Value`
2. return `DateTime(0)` if `_type` is `DateTime`
3. return `null` otherwise

Implementation

```
public static object HandleDBNull(object value, Type _type) {
  if (!object.ReferenceEquals(value, DBNull.Value)) 
    return value;

  if (_type == typeof(DateTime))
    return new DateTime(0);

  return null; 
}
```